# Creating geopackage from multiple raster files?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, geopackage

I've got a bunch of geotiffs' that I would like to combine into a single geopackage. Using QGIS, I've only managed to export one layer as a geopackage. I've tried merging the layers and created a virtual layer but then QGIS messes up the colors.
The raster files are also arranged in a Arcgis Mosaic dataset (file geodatabase) if that is of any help.

Currently, I do the following (which probably isnt the fastest or most efficient way):

1. Generate a .txt-file containing the filenames of all the geotiffs (dir /b /s *.tif > list.txt)
2. Use gdal_merge to merge all the geotiffs from list.txt into one large geotiff (gdal_merge -pct --optfile list.txt -o new_huge_geotiff.tif)
3. Use gdal_translate to convert my new, huge, geotiff into a geopackage (gdal_translate -of GPKG new_huge_geotiff.tif new_tiny_geopackage.gpkg)
4. use gdaladdo to build pyramids in my new geopackage, which I guess also could be done in the previous step when creating the geopackage. I'm just such a newbie. (gdaladdo -r cubic -oo tile_format=JPEG new_tiny_geopackage.gpkg 2 4 6 8 16 32 64)

The process of merging all small geotiffs into one huge takes a lot of time - I wish I could just add them all to a geopackage at once. I've tried using --optfile and the generated txt-list but gdal_translate doesnt like that command.

Comment: Should there be one raster table for each image or would all the geotiffs go to one aggregated table?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I guess any of the two would work as long as all the images are combined into one geopackage. I've got a software that reads geopackage but doesnt read geotiff, thats the reason why I want to combine them.

Comment: Mess with the colors may mean that you have paletted images which has different palettes. Are your images perhaps topographic maps or alike?

Comment: Yeah, it's a topographical map.

Comment: In that case it is easier to create a new table for each image, otherwise you must make the palettes fit or convert the images into non-paletted RGB images first.

Answer (score 13):

New raster tables must be added into existing GeoPackage as subdatasets as documented in the GDAL driver manual page http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage_raster.html. Have a look at the fifth example

> Addition of a new subdataset to an existing GeoPackage, and choose a
>   non default name for the raster table.

`gdal_translate -of GPKG new.tif existing.gpkg -co  APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=new_table`

There is no user interface in QGIS for giving the extra parameters so you must edit the automatically generated gdal_translate command manually. For example if you have an existing GeoPackage "test.gpkg" and you want to add image "Img_Sample.tif" as a new raster table named as "Img_Sample_2" edit the command to look like this:

[image]

If you have lots of images to convert i would suggest to forget QGIS and graphical user interface and use gdal_translate directly from command line with a little script.