# Name output table using gdal_translate in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

How can I name the output table using gdal_translate in QGIS GUI? I dont want the same name on the *.gpkg file as the raster.

LAYER_NAME doesnt work when I try:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Creating geopackage from multiple raster files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278048/creating-geopackage-from-multiple-raster-files), it seems you need to set `RASTER_TABLE=orto_copy` for the `-co` option instead of `LAYER_NAME=orto_copy`

Also mentioned in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#creation-options